# 400 Errors moving files by REST API (Long URL)

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, move

In SharePoint Online, I'm trying to move files that are in a folder in a library to another folder in another library. I'm running a console app to do this so using the API.

I'm mostly there but getting URL Length 400 error "The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value." for some files using this query:

```
odataQuery = $"_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/{subsite}/{sourceLibrary}/{Folder}/{r.Name}')/moveto(newurl='/{subsite}/{destLibrary}/{Folder}/{r.Name}',flags=1)";
```

Which gives this URL:

https://organisation.sharepoint.com/sites/Dynamics365Sandbox/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Dynamics365Sandbox/account/Test%20Account_231A283D5B33E811811D5065F38A4A41/some%20long%20filename.doc')/moveto(newurl='/sites/Dynamics365Sandbox/accountt/Test%20Account_231A283D5B33E811811D5065F38A4A41/some%20long%20filename.doc',flags=1)

I'm trying to find a way to do this using the UniqueId of the file but I'm unsure which part of the URL is causing the problem and how to resolve it.

I've tried this but get a malformed URL error "Bad Request":

```
odataQuery = $"_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{subsite}/{sourceLibrary}')/items?$select=id&$filter=Id eq '{r.UniqueId}'/moveto(newurl='/{subsite}/{destLibrary}/{Folder}/{r.Name}',flags=1)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get around this limitation is to pass both the source and destination as aliases in the query string.

```
var source = $"/{subsite}/{sourceLibrary}/{Folder}/{r.Name}";
var destination = $"/{subsite}/{destLibrary}/{Folder}/{r.Name}";

odataQuery = $"_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@source)/moveto(newurl=@destination,flags=1)?@source='{source}'&@destination='{destination}'";
```

Comment: Nicely done - it works on my first test with an erroneous file name. Have you doubled up the single quotes in the appended query string?

Comment: I just made a change to the source/destination variables as I hadn't updated the values with the $ and double quotes.

Comment: I am getting BAD Request Error when moving file to different site-subsite. Any idea?

Comment: What language is this? How to do it on python?

Comment: No worries, it worked well with python! Thank you~